# Intermediate Value theorem, $nth$ root function and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

[image]

So this problem is.. ridiculous to be honest. I have no idea where to start or what to do. Any help is appreciated. For the record, I am using the metric spaces definition of continuity.

Comment: First establish that $f(x) = x^{n}$ is continuous for all $x$ (this is easy via rules of limits). Then we have $f(0) = 0$. Also the result in question is true if $a = 1$. If $0 < a < 1$ then we can see that $f(1) = 1$ and we have $0 = f(0) < a < f(1) = 1$. And if $a > 1$ then we know that $f(a) > a$ so that again we have $f(0) < a < f(a)$. Now use IVT to get a $c > 0$ such that $f(c) = a$. Show that $c$ is unique. The second question regarding continuity of the inverse function $\sqrt[n]{x}$ is bit tricky but not difficult.

Comment: Ah, thank you, this definitely helps me get started. Although, i must ask (since I don't see it immediately) why do we need that $x^n$ is continuous for this proof?

Comment: IVT holds for continuous functions. So you need to establish continuity of $x^{n}$.

Comment: We're trying to show that there is a unique root of the $nth$ root of $x$ right? so don't we need continuity of that function? Perhaps im not thinking of this correctly.

Comment: I will provide an answer (which will not be complete and will allow you to fill the gaps).

Comment: Alright, thank you! You have helped me before and I look forward to it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we start with showing that $f(x) = x^{n}$ is continuous for all $x$ (actually we need only non-negative values of $x$). OP should be able to prove this by using the fact that $x^{n} = x \cdot x \cdots x\text{ (}n\text{ times})$ where $n$ is fixed positive integer and then using product rule of limits.

Next we need to show that for any $a > 0$ there is a unique $n^{\text{th}}$ root of $a$. What this means is that we have to show the existence and uniqueness of a number $c > 0$ such that $c^{n} = a$. First we show that $c$ (if it exists) is unique. *How??* Suppose there are two such values $c, d$ such that $c^{n} = a = d^{n}$ and $c \neq d$. Now use $$0 = c^{n} - d^{n} = (c - d)(c^{n - 1} + c^{n - 2}d + \cdots + cd^{n - 2} + d^{n - 1})$$ and you can see the obvious contradiction here.

Now we need to see the existence of $c$. If $a = 1$ then obvious $c = 1$. If $0 < a < 1$ then we know that $0 = f(0) < a < f(1) = 1$. If $a > 1$ then $f(a) > a$ so that $f(0) < a < f(a)$. Thus in any case we have a relation of the form $f(0) < a < f(b)$ for a suitable value of $b$. Now use IVT for continuous function $f(x)$.

First part of the problem is now established. The second part deals with showing that $f(x) = x^{n}$ is invertible in the domain $[0, \infty)$ and the inverse function, namely the $n^{\text{th}}$ root function is also continuous. For existence of inverse functions *what do we need?* We need to show that the original function $f(x)$ is a bijection (one-one and onto). From first part of the question itself you should be able to show that $f(x) = x^{n}$ is one-one (this is same logic we used for uniqueness of $c$) and onto (this is same logic we used for existence of $c$ above).

So the inverse function $g(x)$ for $x \geq 0$ exists such that $f(g(x)) = x = g(f(x))$ for all $x \geq 0$. This function we denote by $g(x) = \sqrt[n]{x} = x^{1/n}$. Next challenge is to show the continuity of $g(x)$. This is tricky.

Let $a > 0$ and we will show that $g(x)$ is continuous at $x = a$. Let $b = g(a) = a^{1/n}$ then $b > 0$ and $b^{n} = a$. Also we write $y = g(x) = x^{1/n}$ so that $y^{n} = x$. Now we can see that $$x - a = y^{n} - b^{n} = (y - b)(y^{n - 1} + y^{n - 2}b + \cdots + yb^{n - 2} + b^{n - 1})$$ Suppose that $x \to a^{+}$ so that $x > a$ and we need to show that $y = g(x) \to g(a) = b$. We can see clearly that $y > b$ and hence $$y^{n - 1} + y^{n - 2}b + \cdots + yb^{n - 2} + b^{n - 1} > nb^{n - 1}$$ It follows that $$0 < y - b < \frac{x - a}{nb^{n - 1}} $$ Now using sqeeze theorem and letting $x \to a^{+}$ we get $\lim_{x \to a^{+}}(y - b) = 0$ or $\lim_{x \to a^{+}}y = b$. Similarly we can handle $x \to a^{-}$.

The case $a = 0, b = 0$ requires a different approach. You should try that by using simple inequalities.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing, thank you so much @Paramanand Singh

Comment: last question: do you think the problem wants me to explicitly show that $g$ is the inverse of $f$ through the $g(f(x) = x$ business, or is the statement you have made enough?

Comment: no you don't need to show that $g(f(x))=x$. This is just a property of inverse functions which i have mentioned. The theorem is like this: If $f: A \to B$ is a one-one, onto function (i.e. a bijection from $A$ to $B$ then there exists an inverse $g : B \to A$ such that $g(f(x)) = x = f(g(x))$. You only need to show the bijection part.

Comment: true, but how do we know what the inverse is from this construction?

Comment: In the first part of the problem we have proved that for any $a \geq 0)$ there is a unique $c \geq 0$ such that $c^{n} = a$. Now we have $f(x) = x^{n}$. The inverse $g$ is defined as follows. Let $x \geq 0$ then $g(x)$ is the unique value $y$ such that $y^{n} = x$. Now check that $$f(g(x)) = f(y) = y^{n} = x$$

Comment: okay, one last question (promise). let's assume I want to show that some function is bijective. can I jump right into showing its injective and surjective, or do I have to show its continuous first?

Comment: Bijection is a property which is very very different from continuity. Bijection is more of a set theoretic simple property (i studied this in class 9 when I was 14 year old) and continuity is calculus/analysis stuff (which I studied when I was 16 years old). Don't mix these two things. A bijection guarantees an inverse. A continuous bijection guarantees that both the normal and inverse function are monotone and inverse is also continuous in this case.

Comment: Damn, where you did get educated? I didnt learn about these ideas until college (I am in the US.)

Comment: Well I am from India (check profile) and I believe each country has its own education system and syllabus. I don't think any one country is better or worse than the other. Each has some strengths and some weaknesses.

Comment: Meh, I don't think math education here is very good to be honest.